# vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device : driver message

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, vga

I sometimes get this
 `vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device in dmesg.` The screen flashes a lot at boot, and at times I can booted into tty.
Then I can ctrl+alt+f7 to get a desktop environment.
Output of dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23381803/

Any guesses guys? similar problems https://chakralinux.org/bugtracker/index.php?do=details&task_id=1332  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=216155

Other details:

1. Output of lspci and /var/log/Xorg.0.log
   http://paste.ubuntu.com/23381786/ .
2. Output of lshw http://paste.ubuntu.com/23381790/

VGA card:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
```

OS and kernel:

```
 ~  lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon User Edition 5.8
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
 ~  uname -a
Linux neon 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Since this might be related to nvidia:

```
~  dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-361                                      361.42-0ubuntu2                            amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 361.42
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-361                           361.42-0ubuntu2                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.2                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 361.42-0ubuntu1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

EDIT: 
Running a few more times, sometimes it also shows me a segfault which may explain:

```
Error: 111.183169] sddm[980]: segfault at 40 ip 0000000000000040 sp 00007fff1f7f8b78 error 14 in sddm[400000+6f000]
```

Output of dmesg: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23386861/
Output of cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23386867/

Comment: I have same error in dmesg on Xubuntu 16.10 but for me it boot normally and it crash after some time and I need to login again. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I have the same message, and my laptop became headless - no tty either. However - `lspci | grep -i VGA` returns no lines. I guess this means I have a server now...